# Increase JavaScript Heap Memory in Electron Renderer Process

Tags: google-chrome, electron, heap-memory

My Electron application needs a huge amount of memory in the renderer process. Yes, that's intended and no, there's no way around it. (At least none that would make any sense.)

Using `performance.memory` in the renderer process gives: `jsHeapSizeLimit: 3760000000`. And I can indeed allocate memory up to about 3.5 GB, then the process will crash.

Now, there's the `--max-old-space-size` command line parameter to control the available JS heap size of the renderer process in an Electron app. I set it in `main.js` like this:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=1024')
```

Using `performance.memory` now shows: `jsHeapSizeLimit: 1130000000`, which is just a little bit more than 1GB, so decreasing the JS heap size works. But I cannot *increase* it to more than the 3,760,000,000 bytes.

Trying to set it to 8 GB doesn't increase the JS heap size limit:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=8192')
```

`performance.memory` still says: `jsHeapSizeLimit: 3760000000`

What am I missing? Is `max-old-space-size` only able to reduce available memory and not to increase it? Or do I have to set another parameter so that the renderer process can utilize the available old space?

The important parts of `process.versions`:

```
{
  node: '14.16.0',
  v8: '8.9.255.24-electron.0',
  electron: '12.0.4',
  chrome: '89.0.4389.114'
}
```

This happens on my Macbook with 16GB as well as on my Windows desktop with 64 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found the answer to your question.
However there is this Github thread that gave an answer :
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2056

What work for me (electron 11.5.0) is to add `--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8192` in the `packge.json` script :

```
{
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron --js-flags=--max-old-space-size=8192 main.js"
  }
}
```